# Exporting Juypter Notebook as PDF directly to Teams via a Script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, export, export-to-pdf

I have created an automated status report for a project I am working on using a Jupyter Notebook. The report pulls key metrics from an excel and leverages Poltly to visualise this information using custom graphs. I would like to create a python script at the bottom of my Jupyter notebook to convert the notebook to a PDF and export this to a shared location.

Does anyone have any experience of doing this? I would like to avoid having to manually export the file as a PDF and upload it to the desired location.

Any tips and tricks would be greatly appreciated, thank you!